# An example subset of group such that its not subset of normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I read book of Dummit and Foot Abstract algebra. I need some help with the following question

Let $H$ be a subgroup $G.$ Show that $H$ is subgroup of $N_G(H).$

> Give an example to show that this is not  necessarily true if $H$ is not subgroup.

I can prove that $H$ is subgroup of $N_G(H):$  since subgroup is closed  under products and inverses then $\forall h,a \in H$ we have $ hah^{-1} \in H,$ thus $ h \in N_G(H)$ But I cannot give an example to show that **this is not  necessarily true if $H$ is not subgroup**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\;S_3\;$ , take $\;H=\{(12)\,,\,\,(13)\}\;$ . Then, for example

$$(12)^{-1}(13)(12)=(23)\notin H\implies (12)\notin N_{S_3}(H)$$